# How to create a link in jQuery in a valid way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At [this site](https://github.com/AlexLibs/client-side-csv-generator), the blogger suggest a creation of a link using the syntax below.

```
$('<a>clicky clicky</a>', { href: dataLink, download: fileName });
```

However, I don't get it to work. I need to use the syntax as follows.

```
$('<a href="' + dataLink + '">clicky clicky</a>');
```

Not being familiar with the former, I wonder if I'm missing something. Is that a valid jQuery?

Also, tha tbegs the question of what to do with the *download* attribute. Is the first line of code equivalent to the one below? I have a feeling it's not.

```
$('<a href="' + dataLink + '" download="' + dataLink + '">clicky clicky</a>');
```

Comment: Remove `}` from your last attempt. You must be getting error in your console. Your code will work, However I will always goes with the first one as it much cleaner and makes life lot easier that using quotes.

Comment: @Satpal That was a typo, now corrected, due to copy/paste when typing the question. However, the issue is still bugging me. Are those (1st and 3rd equivalent)?

Answer (score 2):

Use `prop()`:

```
var link = $('<a>clicky clicky</a>').prop({href: dataLink, download: fileName});

var link = $('<a>').prop({href: dataLink, download: fileName , text:'clicky clicky'});
```

Comment: Is the syntax in the first example in my question not a valid jQuery code? Or is it equivalent to the third sample line?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this following code!

```
<script>    
    var download = "logo11w"; /*give your file name*/
    var dataLink = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"; /*path*/
    var mylink= $("<a href='"+dataLink+"'download='"+download+"'>click</a>");
    $("#main").append(mylink);
</script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers my question. I'm not seeing it.